# OpenCV detect and trace darkest lines on image and overlay a grid

Tags: python, opencv, scikit-image

I am trying to recreate the tracings on an EKG and then overlay them onto a new grid but I am stuck with how to best trace the actual tracings. In the images that follow, there are 6 separate tracings I'd like to recreate on essentially a white background with a grid. Any help would be appreciated.

I have managed to find the edges and crop this from a jpg so all I am left with is this image:[image]

I am trying to detect the tracings with either OpenCV's findContours or Hough Line transformations but my edge findings after a gaussian blur leaves me with: [image].. which isn't very helpful.

The hough lines look like this:[image]

Can someone point me in the right direction? Thanks in advance.

Edit:

I did the Local Histogram and then a gaussian blur and another Canny edge detection. The local histogram image was:[image]

and then the canny edge detection was:
[image]

Comment: Optimal canny edge detection?

Comment: before that try pre-processing your image

Comment: I found those edges with canny and it just came out like that, are there certain settings to adjust?

Comment: Find median of the image and set threshold based on that...

Comment: i tried that but now the background grid and the tracings are the same and edge detection detects both

Comment: I just tried localized histogram equalization. after that perform the above

Comment: the histogram equalization gets the lines to be darker, but a messy edge detection

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135806/discussion-between-jeru-luke-and-nahata5).

Comment: Do you have a higher resolution image available?

Comment: The original uncropped image is >2Mb which is over the imgur limit for SO, here is the link for the original http://imgur.com/KeOIeYJ

Comment: I'd suggest to try some local thresholding (binarization) methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using the Sobel and Laplacian detectors as follows

```
img = cv2.imread('experiment.png')
img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
img = cv2.GaussianBlur(img,(3,3),0)
laplacian = cv2.Laplacian(img,cv2.CV_64F)    
sobelx = cv2.Sobel(img,cv2.CV_64F,1,0,ksize=1) 

figure = plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))

sobel = figure.add_subplot(1,2,1)
sobel.imshow(sobelx,cmap='gray')
sobel.set_title('Sobel in x')
sobel.set_axis_off()

laplacianfig = figure.add_subplot(1,2,2)
laplacianfig.imshow(laplacian,cmap='gray')
laplacianfig.set_title('Laplacian')
laplacianfig.set_axis_off()
```

give you the following output

[image]

As you can see, the Sobel operator can be used to detect the lines. Maybe you can then plot those points where the pixel intensities are below the mean.